# Where are Prometheus errors for unfulfilled node-exporter pods?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Installed Prometheus with:

`helm install --name promeks --set server.persistentVolume.storageClass=gp2 stable/prometheus`

Only saw 7 node-exporter pods created but there are 22 nodes.

`$ kubectl get ds promeks-prometheus-node-exporter`

```
NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
promeks-prometheus-node-exporter   22        7         7         7            7           <none>          11d
```

`$ kubectl describe ds promeks-prometheus-node-exporter`

```
$ kubectl describe ds promeks-prometheus-node-exporter
Name:           promeks-prometheus-node-exporter
Selector:       app=prometheus,component=node-exporter,release=promeks
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         app=prometheus
                chart=prometheus-7.0.2
                component=node-exporter
                heritage=Tiller
                release=promeks
Annotations:    <none>
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 22
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 20
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 20
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 20
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  20 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=prometheus
                    component=node-exporter
                    release=promeks
  Service Account:  promeks-prometheus-node-exporter
  Containers:
   prometheus-node-exporter:
    Image:      prom/node-exporter:v0.16.0
    Port:       9100/TCP
    Host Port:  9100/TCP
    Args:
      --path.procfs=/host/proc
      --path.sysfs=/host/sys
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /host/proc from proc (ro)
      /host/sys from sys (ro)
  Volumes:
   proc:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /proc
    HostPathType:
   sys:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /sys
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>
```

In which Prometheus pod will I find logs or events where it is complaining that 15 pods can't be scheduled?

Comment: did you try - kubectl  get pod --all-namespaces ?

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using?
Have you tried to change number of nodes to 15 and then back to 22?
Please provide whole output for `kubectl describe ds promeks-prometheus-node-exporter`
Also please check if you dont have any Taints on nodes `kubectl describe nodes | grep -A3 Taints`
Check if you don't have any restricted quotas on nodes `kubectl describe node | grep -A10 'Allocated resources:'`

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces | grep Pending` returns nothing.  What are you expecting to see there?

Comment: @PjoterS Added full output of describe above.  There are no Taints.  No nodes are overcommitted as far as resources because my manifests don't specify resource requirements (I know, bad practice).  Some ARE overcommitted in terms of pod count but I'm asking: where would I see that error message?  I would expect a complaint in the prometheus deployment somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your issue, however not sure if root cause was the same.

1)
You can get all events from whole cluster

```
kubeclt get events
```

In your case when have 22 nodes it would be better if you use grep

```
kubectl get events | grep Warning
```

or

```
kubectl get events | grep daemonset-controller
```

2)
SSH to node withoud pod. Use command

```
docker ps -a
```

Locate CONTAINER ID from entry where NAMES include node name.

```
docker inspect <ContainerID>
```

You will get a lot informations about container which may help you define why it is failing.

In my case I had issue with PersistentVolumeClaim (did not have gp2 storage class) and insufficient CPU resources.

Storage class can be obtain by

```
kubectl get storageclass
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfiltered `kubectl get events` only has three messages.  None are related to prometheus.  This *did* help determine your same storageclass issue on another cluster but the topic of this post is seeing errors due to pods that cannot deploy.

Comment: What if you will use `kubectl get events --all-namespaces` still not much information? Could you include in main question output of `kubectl cluster-info` ?